# How to give specific attribute to the last process of insertAfter() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, insertafter

Is there anyone who knows on how to give particular attribut (a class in this case), on the last attempt of insertAfter() in jQuery?

For instance,

Before:

```
<td class="column-timesheet-travel">
</td>
<td class="column-timesheet-travel">
</td>
```

After `$('<td class="column-timesheet-work"></td>').insertAfter(".column-timesheet-travel")`, it should be something like:

```
<td class="column-timesheet-travel">
</td>
<td class="column-timesheet-work">
</td>
<td class="column-timesheet-travel">
</td>
<td class="column-timesheet-work NewClassAddedOnLastAttempt">
</td>
```

Or is there any other better way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you not just put that class in the HTML you're adding...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unfortunately I couldn't. Because in the case of my project, the user can customize the page. So, I need to manage the html and css with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Don't add the class name at all, just use `.column-timesheet-work:last-child { /* CSS here */}` in your CSS?

Comment: @DavidThomas Well, for some reasons I can't do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before insert the HTML update store the inserted div on a var and them insert anywehre you need:

`var $div = $('<td class="column-timesheet-work YOU-COULD-PUT_YOUR-CSS-HERE">TD 3</td>').addClass('or-add-this-way');
$('.column-timesheet-travel').last().after($div);`

The example could be done in two ways, adding the class you need, replacing " YOU-COULD-PUT_YOUR-CSS-HERE" or using the method addClass of jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/wallynm/2rjyLd7m/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That `$('.column-timesheet-travel').last().after($div);` gives me the clue.

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful for the others, this is my solution: I do the `$('.column-timesheet-work').last().addClass('column-timesheet-total');` right after I do the insertAfter();

Answer (score 0):

Just another trick way:

```
 $('.column-timesheet-travel').after('<td class="column-timesheet-work"></td>').last().next().addClass('new');
```

"last()" means last td with class '.column-timesheet-travel' and "next()" element is 
what you just ".after()"